# Cloud Function Can not Get Correct Pub/Sub MEssage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am setting up a pub/sub trigger-based cloud function in GCP, the topic the cloud function listen to is us-pubsub1. When I deployed the cloud function and used the testing panel to send messages like:

```
{"index":123,
"video_name":'test.mp4'}
```

in cloud function to processing the message with key index and video_name, it has no issue. But when I sent a real message to us-pubsub1 to trigger the cloud function, it always failed for not able to find the 'index' in the message body. and when reading the pub/sub message in cloud function, it return me messages like:

> {'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage',
> 'attributes': None, 'data':
> 'eyJzZXNzaW9uX2lkIjogImUzYjM0MTJiLWQxNWUtNDM5My05YjEyLWI3ZGY1ZGE4MTQ0NCIsICJzZXNzaW9uX25hbWUiOiAiU0VTU0lPTl9DMjIjMwMTI1VDIwMTI1NCIsICJzaXRlX25hbWUiOiAiVkEgTUVESUNBTCBDRU5URVIgLSBQQUxPIEFMVE8gLSc3RlY3RvbXkiLCAiaHViX3NlcmlhbF9udW1iZXIiOiAiQzIyNC0wMDIwNSIsICJjYXN0X2FwcF92ZXJzaW9uIjogIjEyLjAuMzIuNyIsICJkdl9zeXN0ZW0iOiAiVUFUU0syMDA3IiwgImludGVybmFsX2tleSI6ICJtNjQzY2U1NS0zNjNiLQ=='}

I checked that the message arrive in us-pubsub1 correctly and just failed to process in cloud function.

Is there any thing I have missed for fetching the message body for real cloud function?

Comment: Can you post the code of your cloud function,  please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal. You have a pubsub message enveloppe and your content is base64 encoded in the data field. Here the [documentation details](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage)

---

FWIW, here the real content of your sample

```
{"session_id": "e3b3412b-d15e-4393-9b12-b7df5da81444", "session_name": "SESSION_C22#3#UC##SB"'6FUR#%dTD44TDU"Dstectomy", "hub_serial_number": "C224-00205", "cast_app_version": "12.0.32.7", "dv_system": "UATSK2007", "internal_key": "m643ce55-363b-
```

*it is truncated, you might not share the whole content ;)*